# exclude functions from jasmine firing?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How do you exclude functions from jasmine firing?

Say I have a function call get_chats() that fires when a controller is set up, how do I exclude this from firing as a whole when checking if the controller is instantiated.

Cheers.

Code:

```
//Spec

    require("/tijasmine/tijasmine").infect(this);

    describe("RegisterForm controller", function() {
        var Alloy = require("alloy");
        var $;

        it('Load RegisterForm Controller.', function() {
            $ = Alloy.createController('registerForm', {});

            expect($.__iamalloy).toEqual(true);
        });

    });

Controller:

default_data();
```

The controller function is instantiated at run time, even though all I am interested in is just seeing if the controller loads up without the actual implementation in that function firing.

Cheers

Update:

One way of solving it is to place the function in an event handler:

```
$.win.addEventListener('open', onOpen);

function onOpen(e) {
    get_Chats();
}
```

This way I can purely test if the controller has been instantiated.

Although this does not exclude functions from jasmine that may be nested within another one from being fired.

Comment: You will probably need to provide some code we can talk about. But geneally spoken: you'll stub out this function in a `beforeEach()` closure (and reset it in an `afterEach()`). You can do this by either saving the original function _or it's prototype_ and replacing it in the testee or [creating a spy](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) (Jasmine 2.0 docs).